# I want to stop CMD when run C++ .exe

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-errors, mingw

Thank you for your time. i write simple C++ hello world program with netbeans.It is working well with netbeans. I complied it with MinGW and run the myprogram.exe. At that time it is open with CMD. How to stop this CMD? That is my simple code.

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world","Warning!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
}
```

As well as i attached that CMD. Please help me. Is this compiler problem or other one?[image]

Comment: That's not CMD. That's a **console window**.

Comment: thank you for your all of reply. Please kindly simply tell me how to fix it? Can you modify my code?

Comment: By the way, you should always use the `MB_SETFOREGROUND` option of a message box, except when it's abused to present a message sort of in the background without intending immediate user interaction. For example, without this a message box can be presented behind a command interpreter used to invoke the program.

Comment: Apparently in NetBeans you have to modify the compiler/linker options in the project properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>I've looked for a reasonable duplicate of your question, but found only questions with disinformation answers. So:</sup>

The window you see is not the command interpreter, it's a window of the same *kind* as used by the command interpreter. These are called **console windows**. Your executable produces a new console window because it is by default marked as requiring one, so when it's not run from within a console window, Windows creates a new one for it.

The mark is a value in the executable file's header called its **Windows subsystem**, which determines what basic services it needs from Windows, how Windows should treat it. By default the MinGW tools (and also, for standard code, Microsoft's tools) produce an executable with the **console subsystem**. Usually the only other subsystem used for an ordinary application is the **GUI subsystem**, which is just like the console subsystem except that it says a console window is *not* required.

With MinGW g++ you can use the half-documented option **`-mwindows`** to produce an executable with GUI subsystem.

Alternatively you can specify <sup>[1]</sup>that to the linker, like **`-Wl,-subsystem,windows`**.

Apparently in NetBeans you have to modify the compiler/linker options in the project properties.

With other IDEs it can be as simple as choosing the subsystem via a check-box or in a list.

---

With the MinGW tools you can check the subsystem via the `objdump` utility. And also in other ways. But, using `objdump`:

```
C:\my\forums\so\070>objdump -p a.exe | find /i "sub"
MajorSubsystemVersion   5
MinorSubsystemVersion   2
Subsystem               00000003        (Windows CUI)

C:\my\forums\so\070>g++ foo.cpp -mwindows

C:\my\forums\so\070>objdump -p a.exe | find /i "sub"
MajorSubsystemVersion   5
MinorSubsystemVersion   2
Subsystem               00000002        (Windows GUI)

C:\my\forums\so\070> _
```

With Microsoft's tools you can similarly use their `dumpbin` utility.

There are also many other header dump utilities, but <sup>[2]</sup>Windows does not itself present the subsystem of an executable.

---

With Microsoft's tools there is no compiler option like g++ `-mwindows`, but there is a subsystem *linker option*, `/subsystem:windows`. With this, and standard-conforming code, one must also specify the machine code level **entry point** as the one that calls standard `main`. Namely, linker option `/entry:mainCRTStartup`.

```
C:\my\forums\so\070>cl std.cpp /Feb
std.cpp

C:\my\forums\so\070>dumpbin /headers b.exe | find /i "sub"
            6.00 subsystem version
               3 subsystem (Windows CUI)

C:\my\forums\so\070>cl std.cpp /Feb /link /subsystem:windows /entry:mainCRTStartup
std.cpp

C:\my\forums\so\070>dumpbin /headers b.exe | find /i "sub"
            6.00 subsystem version
               2 subsystem (Windows GUI)

C:\my\forums\so\070> _
```

For working in the command line this can be a little simplified by using the `LINK` environment variable.

Many prefer to instead use Microsoft's monstrosity `main` function replacement, called `WinMain`. This guides Microsoft's linker to assume the GUI subsystem by default. It makes it more <sup>[3]</sup>difficult to build with console subsystem when one desires that, is meaningless from a code point of view, and is non-portable (in particular, g++ accepts the function but ignores its subsystem hinting), as well as horrendously verbose.

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> The `-mwindows` option typically adds some often used Windows API libraries, not added by the simple subsystem linker option. You can check which libraries by dumping a config via the `-dumpspecs` option.

<sup>[2]</sup> I'm talking here about modern Windows. Windows 9.x, in the late 1990s, did present the subsystem values via its (now discontinued) “Quick View” functionality. Which, for an executable, apparently just presented the full textual output from `dumpbin`.

<sup>[3]</sup> With Microsoft's tools, a `WinMain` main function, and console subsystem specified, by default the linker will complain about a missing `main`. One fix is then the linker option `/entry:WinMainCRTStartup`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you all of you. Yes the -mwindows is fixed my problem. I need to know i need to add anything else for better output?

Comment: @Oldmax: You don't *need* to, but to get modern look-and-feel (it varies with each version of Windows, but essentially more colors and less raised) you can add an application description resource (an XML file embedded in the executable) that says it uses "common controls" library 6.0 or later, *and* call `InitCommonControlsEx` specifying the Windows 9x controls as minimum. But that's far more than I can discuss here. It's horrendously complicated for such a simple yes/no decision, do I want modern look or not. I think you can google "visual style". I may have discussed it at my Windows blog.

Comment: If you use Microsoft's Visual Studio IDE (the community edition is free), which only uses their Visual C++ compiler, then in the new project dialog you can just go online and find my Win32 project template with modern look-and-feel support. It also adjusts the compiler to more standard-conforming behavior. And uses a standard `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to ignore the cmd window is to run it silently with the command:

cmd /c yourprogram.exe

this will still run the program but the command prompt will not show.

Comment: how to add your code to my code? You mean at compile time?

Comment: `cmd /c` has nothing to do with *preventing* a console window. It adds an extra invocation of the command interpreter. Which is useless overhead. And in the case of a GUI program it *ensures*  a console window, which seems to be the opposite of what's asked.