# How do we prevent cmd terminal? Java application created with C++ and JVM.dll

Tags: java, c++

How do we prevent cmd terminal from opening in the background of an exe created with C++ and JVM.dll?

How can i prevent or hide this terminal. C++ or Java side...

It runs Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2008. I couldn't find why the problem occurred.
I use below code. But no effect. I write 2 times the code loading gui before and after. Application window goes only minimize.

ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h" 
#include <tchar.h>
#include "jni.h"

using namespace std;
typedef jint(JNICALL* JNICREATEPROC)(JavaVM**, void**, void*);

int main()
{

       ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

    char jvmPath[]="lib\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll";
    JavaVMOption* vmOption = new JavaVMOption[1];
    vmOption[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=brd.jar";
    JavaVMInitArgs vmInitArgs;
    vmInitArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_10;
    vmInitArgs.options = vmOption;
    vmInitArgs.nOptions = 1;
    vmInitArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
    const char startClass[] = "BarkodGenerator/Barcode";
    const char startMethod[] = "main";
    HINSTANCE jvmDLL = LoadLibrary(jvmPath);
    if (jvmDLL == NULL) {
        //cout << "load jvm error" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    JNICREATEPROC createJavaVm = (JNICREATEPROC)GetProcAddress(jvmDLL, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
    if (createJavaVm == NULL) {
        FreeLibrary(jvmDLL);
        //cout << "load JNI_CreateJavaVM err" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVM* jvm;
    jint jvmProc = (createJavaVm)(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vmInitArgs);
    if (jvmProc < 0 || jvm == NULL || env == NULL) {
        FreeLibrary(jvmDLL);
        //cout << "create jvm error" << endl;
        return false;
    }
   
    jclass mainclass = env->FindClass(startClass);
    if (env->ExceptionCheck() == JNI_TRUE || mainclass == NULL) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        env->ExceptionClear();
        FreeLibrary(jvmDLL);
        //cout << "load main class error" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    jmethodID methedID = env->GetStaticMethodID(mainclass, startMethod, "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (env->ExceptionCheck() == JNI_TRUE || methedID == NULL) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        env->ExceptionClear();
        FreeLibrary(jvmDLL);
        //cout << "load main method error" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(mainclass, methedID, NULL);
    //jvm sürümü
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to stop CMD when run C++ .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870490/i-want-to-stop-cmd-when-run-c-exe)

Comment: No this is not.

Comment: Instead of the `ShowWindow` call you can try to call [FreeConsole()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole). Disclaimer - I haven't used it myself, found it during a search. It looks like  a bit of a hack but it might solve your problem. If it seems to work I advise to read a bit more about it to make sure there's no unwanted side effect.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where is the Java code? What is the application expected to do?

Comment: Build your C++ program as a Windows application, not a console application. It should have a `WinMain` entry point. When the code reaches your `main` it's already too late the console was created for you.

Comment: All java packages give the same result. The cmd terminal always appears in the background.

Comment: I write FreeConsole(); begining of the code and problem is solve. Thank you very much for all your reply.

Comment: What @ixe013 is the correct solution.

Comment: LMGTFY and find https://stackoverflow.com/a/3884179/591064